# blocky - property of undefined

Tags: javascript, blockly

I am trying to create a custom block in `blockly` but can't seems to get it to work. I generated code from [block factory](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/blockfactory/index.html) and this is what I got:

```
//say_input.js

Blockly.Blocks['say_input'] = {
  init: function() {
    this.appendDummyInput()
        .appendField("say")
        .appendField(new Blockly.FieldTextInput("something"), "say_input");
    this.setColour(230);
 this.setTooltip("");
 this.setHelpUrl("");
  }
};

Blockly.JavaScript['say_input'] = function(block) {
  var text_say_input = block.getFieldValue('say_input');
  // TODO: Assemble JavaScript into code variable.
  // var code = 'alert("Hello! I am an alert box and'+text_say_input+'!");';
  var code = '...;\n';
  return code;
};
```

then I import it into my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blockly Demo: Fixed Blockly</title>
    <script src="js/blockly_compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="js/blocks_compressed.js"></script>
    <script src="js/msg/js/en.js"></script>

    <script src="js/blocks/say_input.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        h1 {
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 140%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="runCode()">Click me</button>
    <div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 480px; width: 600px;"></div>

    <xml id="toolbox" style="display: none;">
        <block type="say_input">
            <field name="say_input">something</field>
        </block>
    </xml>

    <script>
        var demoWorkspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {
            media: 'js/media/',
            toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')
        });

        function runCode(){
            window.LoopTrap = 1000;
            Blockly.JavaScript.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP = 
            'if(--window.LoopTrap == 0) throw "Infinite loop."\n';
            var code = Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspace);
            Blockly.JavaScript.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP = null;
            try {
                eval(code);
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

and load it to browser. immediately I got this error:

> Cannot set property 'say_input' of undefined

The error is at the line:

```
Blockly.JavaScript['say_input'] = function(block) {
```

My custom block appear in the workplace so I am sure the linking is working.

I checked [this video](https://youtu.be/YjGoDh-Qqkg?t=5m2s) and seems like I am doing nothing wrong.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I have to link `javascript_compressed.js` then everything just work.

```
<script src="js/javascript_compressed.js"></script>
```

make sure to link it before the `custom block.js`.